# Android textview right to left

Tags: android, textview, right-to-left

I'm trying to set my textview text from right to left.

I want to use Hebrew language in my application, I've tried using it, everything works fine, except for the numbers, (300 shows 003...etc..)

Comment: "I've tried using it" -- please explain what "it" is. For example, you might consider supplying relevant files from your project, such as layout files, showing how you are taking advantage of Android's RTL support.

Comment: if it is part of text in textview then its  diffcut to manage it instaed write 003 and it will reverse as 300

Comment: @CommonsWare Meaning I used the Hebrew language, everything is fine except for the numbers

Comment: @DIVA The problem is the number is variable (comes from sharedpreference after some activites)

Comment: @SamM simply make a string a reverse it and apperent to textview

Comment: @SamM like u can hv StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(ur sharedpref number +"");
       buffer.reverse()

Comment: @SamM did it worked?can i post answer :P +1 for ur question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just used string to backward the sharedpreferences once getting it.